# How to import existing GCP datastore indexes to index.yaml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I couldn't find any direct way to export existing indexes apart from `gcloud datastore indexes list`

gcloud-list.yaml

```
---                   
ancestor: NONE   
indexId: CICAgOi36pgK 
kind: Session    
projectId: self-serve-dev-261801
properties:      
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: identityId        
- direction: ASCENDING                                                             
  name: endTime                                                                
state: READY                         
---     
ancestor: NONE                                     
indexId: CICAgJj7z4EL                           
kind: Feedback       
projectId: self-serve-dev-261801
properties:          
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: id           
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: entity       
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: value          
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: submitter    
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: createdOn    
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: updatedOn
```

index.yaml

```
indexes:

- kind: Task
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: done
  - name: priority
    direction: desc

- kind: Task
  properties:
  - name: collaborators
    direction: asc
  - name: created
    direction: desc

- kind: TaskList
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: percent_complete
    direction: asc
  - name: type
    direction: asc
```

It's output contains `IndexId` which is not found in actual index.yaml samples.

I want to create a datastore and import this indexes to it using a Terraform module.
I don't know whether the `list` output conflicts if we try to import it from the gcloud cli output as such.

Also values are different `NONE` -> `no`, `ASCENDING` -> `asc`.

I could write a script to convert it to the proper format. Is that the only way?

Comment: This [document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#console_2), describes how to export and import Firestore in Datastore mode entities using the managed export and import service. The managed export and import service is available through the Cloud console, Google Cloud CLI, and the Datastore Admin API (REST, RPC).

Comment: I’m not having much experience in Terraform, and I think writing a script to convert it to the proper format is the only way. you can check the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/datastore_index) or you can reach out to the [Terraform Support Team](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/getting-support).

Comment: There is a tool available to export configurations in terraform format. Unfortunately it does not cover all resource types. As of today Datastore is not covered. More details here https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/export. Available types that can be exported may by listed by gcloud beta resource-config list-resource-types --project=<PROJECT_ID>

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this repo for generating index.yaml file for GCP datastore.
https://github.com/ArunMuthuram/gcpDatastoreIndexYamlGenerator